# Regex ending with pipe character

Tags: regex

How does it affect a regex to have it just end with a pipe character?

example :

```
[0-9]{1,5}|
```

I know the pipe means or, but in this case it's not "orring" anything.  An online tool such as http://regexpal.com/ seems to ignore the extraneous pipe character.  Does anyone know if a regex spec can say anything about how a trailing pipe is supposed to be treated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's still treated as 'or', in your case, it just means it should match 1 to 5 digits, or an empty string.

Note that an empty string can be matched in practically any string.

Comment: OK, if we wanted to match on [0-9]{1,5} OR an empty field, what regex could we use?

Comment: @MikePone If that's so, then I believe the apropriate regex changing as little as possible would be `^([0-9]{1,5}|)$`, but I think that the best one would be `^[0-9]{0,5}$`. `^` matches the beginning of the string, `$` matches the end of the string. Those two ensure that the entire string is checked.

Comment: ok, I also googled it and found `[0-9]{1,5}|^$` as a recommendation.

Comment: @MikePone That will also match a string similar to `abc12345def`. If that's the intended behaviour, then by all means, you should use that :)

Answer (score 0):

It's `OR`ing with an empty string. So it will match an empty input.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex:

```
[0-9]{1,5}|
```

is equivalent to:

```
(?:[0-9]{1,5})?
```

i.e. match 5 digits or match nothing (empty text).